# Dynamically set radio button active using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

i am using jquery mobile horizontal control group radio buttons.

How do i set the first radio button active. The following are the two radio buttons,

```
<input type="radio" name="rating" id="radio-mini-1" value="Above Average" /><label for="radio-mini-1">Above<br /> Average</label>
```

Average

I tried using the following code,

```
$('input:radio[name="rating"]').filter('[value="Above Average"]').attr('checked', true);
```

but no luck. What's wrong?

Comment: could you add your html code?

Comment: You should use `prop` instead of `attr`.
*The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method.*

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use jQueryMobile, the html structure changes, so you have to do some tricks, try this:

```
$('input:radio[name="rating"]').filter('[value="Above Average"]').next().click()
```

if it didn't work, try this:

```
$('input:radio[name="rating"]').filter('[value="Above Average"]').parent().find("label[for].ui-btn").click()
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to call refresh.

```
$(..selector...).attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Comment: spot on - thanks Tom - I've had to do this refresh to force the selector to actually show its checked - except use prop not attr as per another comment in this thread `$(..selector..).prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");`

Answer (score 2):

This function works nicely:

function set_jqm_radio_button( button_name, value ) {

```
$( 'input:radio[name="' + button_name + '"]' ).filter( '[value="' +value + '"]' ).prop( 'checked', true ).checkboxradio( 'refresh' );
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how works jquery mobile but try this

```
$('input:radio[name="rating"]').filter('[value="Above Average"]').prop('checked', true);
```

As [reagten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652211/reagten)'s suggestion, please paste HTML code and I'll update my answer.

But your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/dH69J/

Answer (score -1):

For me it worked as simple as

```
$("#myItem").prop("checked", true)
```

I don't see so complicated as explained above...